# File permission confusion

Tags: php, file-permissions

Found this bit of code in FrogCms

```
function isWritable($file=null) {
  $perms = fileperms($file);
  if (is_writable($file) || ($perms & 0x0080) || ($perms & 0x0010) || ($perms & 0x0002))
    return true;
}
```

I had a hard time understanding this part

```
(is_writable($file) || ($perms & 0x0080) || ($perms & 0x0010) || ($perms & 0x0002))
```

After doing some research i know that `0x0080` is permission for owner, `0x0010` is permission for group and `0x0002` is permission for other.Where do this value come form? Is this is a predetermined value for permission system?

And can someone explain to me for example how `$perms & 0x0080` resolve to true, cause for example `fileperms(__FILE__)` return a value like 33206.How can u 
compare 33206 with 0x0080?

Comment: As permissions are grouped into triplets people normally use octal values for them. Not hex or decimals. It's probably taken from the awful manual example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constants you refer to (`0x0080` etc) do not have the exact meanings you think they do. See the [`fileperms`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) documentation:

```
0x0080 = owner writable
0x0010 = group writable
0x0002 = world writable
```

Also, you are not *comparing* them, you are performing a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

```
    1000000110110110 = 33206 (dec)
    0000000010000000 = 0x80  (hex)
AND ------------------------
    0000000010000000 = result (bin)
```

Since the result is non-zero, this means that the particular file is owner-writable.

**But what does the code you give do?**

Well, it returns `true` if and only if the file is writable by *any* of the following:

- the user that the script runs as (checked by `is_writable`)
- the user that owns the file
- the group that owns the file
- any user

This certainly looks like illogical and buggy to me, because e.g.:

- if e.g. only the owner can write the file the function will return `true`; however, that certainly does not mean the file is writable for *you*, unless you are the owner!
- if the aim is to check if *anyone* could write the file (which is kind of pointless really), the `is_writable` check would be superfluous and at the very least confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> Where do this value come form?

They're hexadecimal equivalents of the permission bits, normally specified in octal.

> Is this is a predetermined value for permission system?

[Yes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions)

> And can someone explain to me for example how `$perms & 0x0080` resolve to true, cause for example `fileperms(__FILE__)` return a value like 33206

```
>>> hex(33206)
'0x81b6'
>>> 0x81b6 & 0x0080
128
```

Non-zero values are true.